# Why isn't Easy-Comment Jquery Plugin showing or working?

Tags: jquery

So for his website, the client decided that he wanted to start making blogs for his company. He also wanted people to be able to share these blogs through social media and for them to leave comments. But he wants to be able to monitor and approve of these comments before they are posted. This site is a full php-coded site so it isn't CMS.

I ended up building the article pages from scratch and using jquery plugins to create the share buttons but I'm having a hard time getting a plugin I had found called 'Easy-Comment' to work or even show up. It's the only plugin I've found that seems to also give the ability to approve comments before they are posted.

**What I've Done:**

Followed the steps on the [Easy-Comment Instructional Page](http://www.jswidget.com/lab/easy-comment.html)

Added

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.your-domain.com/easy-comment/jquery.easy-comment.min.js"></script>
```

To the head of the site before the closing head tag. Then added the following code in a script tag before the closing body tag

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#my-comment").EasyComment({
      path:"easy-comment/"
   });
});
```

To see the full code for the page I'll provide a link to the webpage. I'll also provide a link to a JSFiddle.

[webpage link:](http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/triad-marketing-minute/branding-art-science-identity-blog/index.php)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8fw46u0/)

**Things I have Tried:**

Changing the names of the selectors

Adding 'http://' to the AJAX script tag, source attribute

Changing the order of my scripts (Jquery) first

**Things I have Found:**
When I use Developer tools this error message has popped which leaves me to believe that it might have something to do with the Javascript. Maybe it's conflicting with something else.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).EasyComment is not a function
>      at HTMLDocument. (index.php:80)
>     at Object.resolveWith (jquery.min.js:16)
>      at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:16)
>      at HTMLDocument.y (jquery.min.js:16)

Help from you guys would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: code seems like cool just need to replace `http` to `https` in `scripts` because *FIDDLE* won't allow insecure script. You can see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8fw46u0/1/)

Comment: You are using multiple jquery libraries. Sometimes this will cause errors

Comment: I have put your code on my custom page it's working fine for me

Comment: It seems multiple jquery libraries conflicting with your easy-comment plugin

http://www.freedomcreativesolutions.com/triad-marketing-minute/branding-art-science-identity-blog/index.php

Comment: @PankajMakwana Firstly thanks for responding to this. I figured that might be it. They had a developer add all these libraries in a while back before I started working here. Will I need to get rid of these libraries in order for the plugin to work? How can I do that without screwing up anything else on the site?